# what's the equivalent of atoi or strtoul for uint32_t and other stdint types?

Tags: c, type-conversion, c99, stdint

i'm looking for the standard functions to convert a string to an [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h) integer, like

```
int i = atoi("123");
unsigned long ul = strtoul("123", NULL, 10);
uint32_t n = mysteryfunction("123"); // <-- ???
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two general options: `strto[iu]max` followed by a check to see if the value fits in the smaller type, or switch to `sscanf`. The C standard defines an entire family of macros in `<inttypes.h>` that expand to the appropriate conversion specifier for the `<stdint.h>` types. Example for `uint32_t`:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t n;

    sscanf("123", "%"SCNu32, &n);
    printf("%"PRIu32"\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

(In the case of `uint32_t`, `strtoul` + overflow check would also work for `uint32_t` because `unsigned long` is at least 32 bits wide. It wouldn't reliably work for `uint_least32_t`, `uint_fast32_t`, `uint64_t` etc.)

**Edit**: as Jens Gustedt notes below, this doesn't offer the full flexibility of `strtoul` in that you can't specify the base. However, base 8 and base 16 are still possible to obtain with `SCNo32` and `SCNx32`, respectively.

Comment: +1 but you are loosing the advantage of being able to specify the base.

Comment: @Jens: not entirely. `SCNo32` handles base 8, `SCNx32` base 16; so only the exotic bases and binary aren't covered, binary being trivial to implement.

Comment: @larsmans: The biggest thing missing isn't the exotic bases, it's that `strtouxxx` lets you specify a base of `0`, in which case it is inferred from the number (by interpreting it as an integer constant would be), which can be very useful if you want to allow (say) someone to use both hex and decimal. And, of course, the end pointer is also very, very useful at times.

Comment: @Stephen: You have that power with `scanf` too. Simply use `%i` instead of `%d`, `%o`, `%x`, etc.

Comment: @R..: `%i` is for `signed` target object, though, so it can't be used to replace `strtoul` as simply.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question concerns `unsigned` integers the overflow check is simple. With a little helper function

```
inline
unsigned long long
strtoullMax(const char *nptr,
            char **endptr,
            int base,
            unsigned long long maxval) {
  unsigned long long ret = strtoll(nptr, endptr, base);
  if (ret > maxval) {
     ret = maxval;
     errrno = ERANGE;
  } else {
     if (ret == ULLONG_MAX && errno == ERANGE)
        ret = maxval;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

you easily can define macros that do the trick for any type you are interested in

```
#define strtou32(NPTR, ENDPTR, BASE)                  \
   strtoullMax(NPTR, ENDPTR, BASE, (uint32_t)-1)
#define strtou32f(NPTR, ENDPTR, BASE)                 \
   strtoullMax(NPTR, ENDPTR, BASE, (uint_fast32_t)-1)
#define strtou32l(NPTR, ENDPTR, BASE)                 \
   strtoullMax(NPTR, ENDPTR, BASE, (uint_least32_t)-1)
```

Comment: Why not use `uintmax_t` and `strtoumax`, because `strtoumaxmax` would be too awkward ;) ? Those are safer, since IIRC there's no guarantee that `uint_{fast,least}32_t` will be smaller than `unsigned long long`, while they are smaller than or equal to `uintmax_t` by definition.